# How to get the activity name from activity code in google fit

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am working with google fit . I have activities int value, I want to get the name of the activity from int value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can done with following method of Fittness activity

```
FitnessActivities.getName(activitycode);
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessActivities.html)